# Search recursively for all files with a .sql extension and pass them to mysql as argument

Tags: bash, find

**Given:**

Directory tree that contains files with `.sql` extension.

**Requred**

Find them all recursively and pass found files one by one to `mysql` client as:

`mysql < ./dir/subdir/subsubdir/schema.sql`

**My feeble attempt**

`find . -name '*.sql' | xargs mysql`

Results in:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database './dir/subdir/subsubdir/schema.sql'
```

**Question**

How to do it right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work

```
find . -type f -name '*.sql' -exec bash -c 'cat '{}' | mysql' \;
```

Basically the above finds all files ending in .sql (I put the -type f in there just in case there are any directories that end in .sql).  For each file found, find runs the exec command.  The exec runs a bash sub-shell that cats the file and pipes that to the mysql program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Would this: 1) pipe contents of .sql files into mysql client; or 2) launch shell command `mysql ./schema.sql` ?

Comment: Yes.  For example, if you have a file called schema.sql, the find will run a bash shell that does, cat schema.sql | mysql, which is the equivalent of mysql <schema.sql.  It will not do mysql ./schema.sql.  If you want that, replace the exec with just mysql {} \;

Answer (score 1):

In stead of trying to execute everything, consider going a two step route: collect all paths to files into single file, then use `source` command to run the resulting file

```
find . type f -name '*.sql' -printf 'source  %P;\n'    > allsql.txt
mysql -u <user> -p  -e "source allsql.txt"
```

Of course, if different sql files reference different databases or  have conflicting queries - mysql will throw errors, and therefore even though this may work, this is generally not the best idea.  You also should keep in mind that a database name for which you run queries should be provided on command line or via statement `use <databasename>`.